# Targeting label with css

Tags: css, wordpress

I'd like to target a label with css. How? It's WordPress, a contact form and I've managed to move all the other sections including:`textarea, submit, anr recaptcha` but not the text label.

```
label> Your Name (required)<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">. 
<input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" 
class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates. 
as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" />. 
</span> </label></p>
<p><label> Your Email (required)<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email">. 
<input 
type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40"
class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text
```

Tried:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {label.wpcf7-form- 
control{margin-left: 15px;}}
```

And:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {p 
label.wpcf7-form- 
control{margin-left: 15px;}}
```

And:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) 
{label.wpcf7-form- 
control>.wpcf7-text {margin-left: 
15px;}}
```

Didn't work.

[Page in question](http://4309.co.uk/contact/)

Comment: `label.wpfc7-form-control` as none of your `<label>` elements have a class-name at all, why did you think that this selector would work at all? Just use `label` as the selector. Also note that you're missing the `<` from your first `<label>` element in the code.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried. Doesn't work. It moves the whole form left rather than just the label

Answer (score 0):

The `label` element in your example code doesn't seem to have any class associated with it.

You could simply select it like this:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    label {
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
}
```

...although this would probably be a bad idea, since it will affect ALL the `<label>` elements on your page.

I would look for any wrapper class in the contact form widget, and scope it safely. For example:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .wpcf7-form-wrap label {
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
}
```

PS. All your CSS examples have a typo. You have used `wpfc7` instead of `wpcf7`.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected. Using just `label` as a selector seems to move the whole form left

Comment: And your second example just tried but didn't work. Much appreciate efforts though....

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a wrapper class...?

Comment: *`label` moves whole form left and not just label, which is what I was looking for....

Comment: You should avoid using `*` in your css, it's very slow, not optimal, and can lead to unintended consequences.